# Помогите сделать постраничный вывод php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?
/* Скрипт показывает значения таблицы*/
$hostname = "--";
$username = "--";
$password = "--";
$dbName = "--";

/* Таблица MySQL, в которой хранятся данные */
$userstable = "gm_bans";

/* создать соединение */
MYSQL_CONNECT($hostname,$username,$password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");

@mysql_select_db("$dbName") or die("Не могу выбрать базу данных "); 
/*Кодировка*/
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

/* Выбрать все записи */
$query = "SELECT * FROM $userstable";
$result = MYSQL_QUERY($query);

$users_on_page="5";
$count=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(id) from `$userstable`"));

/* Количество*/
$number = MYSQL_NUMROWS($result);

/* Напечатать всех в красивом виде*/
$i = 1;
IF ($number == 0) {
    PRINT "<CENTER><P>Нет результатов</CENTER>";
} ELSEIF ($number > 0) {
    PRINT "<CENTER><P>Количество: $number";
    PRINT "<table class='bordered bordered2'>";
    PRINT "<TR><TD>Ник игрока</TD><TD>Причина</TD><TD>Ник администратора</TD><TD>Срок бана</TD></TR>";
    WHILE ($i < $number){
        $player_nick = mysql_result($result,$i,"player_nick");
        $ban_reason= mysql_result($result,$i,"ban_reason");
        $admin_nick= mysql_result($result,$i,"admin_nick");
        $ban_length = mysql_result($result,$i,"ban_length");

       if($ban_length == "0"){
           PRINT "<TR><TD>$player_nick</TD><TD>$ban_reason</TD><TD>$admin_nick</TD><TD>Навсегда</TD></TR>";
       } else{ 
           PRINT "<TR><TD>$player_nick</TD><TD>$ban_reason</TD><TD>$admin_nick</TD><TD>$ban_length</TD></TR>";
       };
       $i++;
   }
   PRINT "</table>";
   PRINT "</CENTER>";
}
?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста сделать постраничную навигацию, 4 примера уже попробовал не получается

Comment: $users_on_page="5";
$count=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(id) from `$userstable`")); Лишние строчки

Comment: Перестаньте использовать mysql_*. Оно удалено из версии PHP 7.0. Научитесь писать код в одном регистре (нижнем).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое, что можно использовать для постраничного вывода - это `LIMIT`. Как будто для этого и сделан.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $userstable 
        ORDER BY player_nick, admin_nick, ban_reason, ban_length 
           LIMIT $offset, $page_size";

$countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM $userstable;
```

`$offset` - Самый главной и сложный параметр в этом деле. Он определяет какая страница будет выведена в HTML.
Сервер БД пропускает первые `$offset` строк(и), выбранных запросом и начинает выдачу результатов, начиная со строки номер `$offset + 1`.
`$page_size` - количество записей на странице. наверное то же, что Ваш `$users_on_page`.
Сервер выдаст в результате не более этого количества строк.

Важно чтобы был `ORDER BY`. Порядок должен быть, чтобы не случалось такого, что одни и те же строки будут то на первой, то на десятой странице.

Номер страницы вычисляется по `$offset` и `$page_size`:
`$page_number = $offset % $page_size`. Вроде так.
Можно и по номеру страницы определить требуемый offset:
`$offset = ($page_number - 1) * $page_size`
Количество страниц получают из запроса `$countQuery` и `$page_size`:
`$page_count = ($count / $page_size) + (($count % $page_size) == 0 ? 0 : 1)`

Формируются необходимые кнопки/ссылки навигации. `$page_number` (от 1 до `$page_count`) используется в названии. Надо же как-то показать номер страницы.
Вычисленный `$offset` используется как параметр, который будет передан обратно на сервер при нажатии на кнопку.
В Вашем примере нет никаких элементов навигации по страницам и я не будут ничего придумывать. Идея и так ясна.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
 
// Будем выводить по 2 записи на листе:
$number = 2;
// Читаем сдвиг из GET-массива:
$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? (int)$_GET['offset'] : 0;
// Коннект до базы данных
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) die('Не могу соединиться с базой данных');
// Выбираем базу данных
mysql_select_db('paginator', $link);
// Выполняем запрос 'посчитать число записей'
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`", $link);
// Теперь в переменной $total общее число записей
$total = mysql_result($result, 0);
$menu = getMenuofPages($total, $number, $offset);
?>
<?
function getMenuofPages($total, $number, $offset) {
   // Подфункция определяет есть ли уже в текущем url get-данные
   // и дописывает соответственно нужный offset:
   function getGoodUrl($url, $cur) {
      if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "") {
         return $url."?offset=".$cur;
      }else {
         if (substr_count($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "offset=") > 0) {
            $url = preg_replace("/offset=\d+/i", "offset=".$cur, $url);
            return $url;
         }else {
            return $url."&offset=".$cur;
         }
      }
   }
   // Если общее число меньше числа записей, которые мы должны вывести на
   // странице, то ничего не делаем:
   if ($total <= $number) {
      return;
   }
   $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $int = intval($total / $number); // Целая часть от деления
   $rest = $total % $number; // Остаток от деления
   $menu = "";
   // Сначала перебираем целые части
   for ($i = 0; $i < $int; $i++) {
      $cur = $i * $number;
      if ($cur == $offset) { // Проверка на текущую страницу
         $menu .= "  ".($cur + 1)."-".($cur + $number);
      }else {
         $menu .= "  <a href=\"".getGoodUrl($url, $cur)."\">".
                  ($cur + 1)."-".($cur + $number)."</a>";
      
      }
   }
   // Потом остаток (если есть)
   if ($rest > 0) {
      $cur += $number;
      if ($cur == $offset) { // Проверка на текущую страницу
         if ($rest == 1) {
            $menu .= "  ".($cur + 1)." ";
         }else {
            $menu .= "  ".($cur + 1)."-".($cur + $rest)." ";                         // |
         }
      }else {
         if ($rest == 1) {
            $menu .= "  <a href=\"".getGoodUrl($url, $cur)."\">".($cur + 1)."</a> "; //|
         }else {
            $menu .= "  <a href=\"".getGoodUrl($url, $cur)."\">".
                     ($cur + 1)."-".($cur + $rest)."</a> ";                           //|
         }
      }
   }else {
      $menu .= " ";
   }
   return $menu;
}
?>
<?
// Читаем из базы $number записей начиная с $offset:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $offset, $number", $link);
// Распечатываем результат вывода пагинации:
echo '<div class="pagination">';
echo $menu;
echo '</div>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{?>
      <div class="center" style="background:#fefefe; margin:20px auto;"> 
     <h3>
    <span style="padding:0 10px;background:red;"><?=$row['id'];?></span>
    <span style="padding:0 5px; background:yellow;"><?= $row['autor'];?></span> 
    <span style="padding:0 4px; background:lightblue;"><?= $row['date'];?></span>
  </h3>
  <p> <?= $row['text']; ?> </p>
   </div>
<?}?>
<div class="pagination">
  <? echo $menu ?>
</div>
```

как то так